# Stores category posts in an array

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories

I'm trying to get my posts from my *category.php* file.

The loop works fine, it's showing my custom post types, but I'd like to store the posts from my category to reorder them in a certain way.

How do I do that ? Tried to use `get_posts()`, the it return the 3 first post of the 'post' post type.

```
    <?php
    if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <section class="playlist_row row">
            <div class="col-12 owl-container" id="<?= "";?>">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <?php
                while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php get_template_part("template-parts/card/playlist", "card"); ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php
    else: ?>
        <p>Aucun résultat.</p>


    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: I'm using the default wordpress query for the category.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Howard E said, without knowing more about what and how you want to reorder it's difficult to give you useful advice. [Here's a good breakdown of the options](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/66368) and, here are some places to start.

1. If you want an array of posts to order your own way, you can use the native function [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) in order to create an array of posts based on selected arguments. More info [here](https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-get_posts/).
2. If you want to modify the existing loop on your archive page and order youor posts with custom arguments, you can use [`pre_get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/)
3. If you want to write use existing WordPress arguments to order your posts, you can write a custom query using [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) and [the ordering arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters) it already supports.

**Update**

Since you want to sort your posts by a custom ACF field, here's how to do that with `get_posts()`:

```
// get posts
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'event',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'start_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));
```

ACF has an [entire page dedicated to sorting by custom field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/orde-posts-by-custom-fields/). You shouldn't need to put the posts back in an array in order to sort them.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm using the default query, just alter it by adding a custom post type in the query. For the reorder, it's gonna be I think an ACF reorder, but I need first to get my data in my template...

Comment: Great, answer updated to include ACF values too.